# Is there a way that I can create a "border" around a string in gtk?

Tags: button, gtk, border

My first GUI experiences goes back to 1996 with Xaw`and Xlib.  After 2004 i gave up and went back to a CLI.  Now i need to create a small GUI "widget[?]" that starts with a "0" at the bottom and above has two buttons "inc" and "dec".  Above this, at the top is the string

Filename ***_*___**

the inc/dec buttons increase/decrease the filename.

For example, if the user types in speak, at the bottom, the "0" would become

speak.0.text.  the inc/decrease buttons would change the bottom string up or down, NOT below 0.

I am stuck right now trying to make the "0" or ".0.text stand out.   I have tried to but  the filename.N.text into a gtk button. gcc either cores or refuses to compile.

can anybody suggest way to put a border around the "0" or otherwise make it stand out?

thanks muchly.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the border kind of effect is available right away but there are other font related changes you can make using [`Pango Markup`](http://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html) to highlight your text using `gtk_label_set_markup`. Also you can make the decrementing button as insensitive using `gtk_widget_set_sensitive` when the counter reaches 0 so that it cannot be decreased further. Here is sample code for your reference:

```
/*
 * Compilation : gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` -Wall -Wextra -Werror label-sample.c -o label-sample
 */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

static int counter = 0;
static GtkWidget *label;
static char *suffix = ".txt";
static char *prefix;


static void
update_label(void)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);

    /*If counter is < 1, use markup to highlight text*/
    if(counter < 1)
    {
        if(prefix)
            g_snprintf(buffer, 1023, "<span foreground=\"red\" background=\"yellow\" size=\"x-large\">%s%d%s</span>",prefix, counter, suffix);
        else
            g_snprintf(buffer, 1023, "<span foreground=\"red\" background=\"yellow\" size=\"x-large\">%d%s</span>", counter, suffix);
        gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        if(prefix)
            g_snprintf(buffer, 1023, "%s%d%s", prefix, counter, suffix);
        else
            g_snprintf(buffer, 1023, "%d%s", counter, suffix);
        gtk_label_set_label(GTK_LABEL(label), buffer);
    }
}

static void
inc_button_click_cb(GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
{
    (void)button;
    GtkWidget *dec_button = data;
    counter++;
    /* Change senstivity of the decrement button based on counter*/
    if(counter > 0 && !gtk_widget_is_sensitive(dec_button))
        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(dec_button, TRUE);
    /* Update label to show updated counter */
    update_label();
    return;
}

static void
dec_button_click_cb(GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
{
    (void)data;
    counter--;
    /* Change senstivity of the decrement button based on counter*/
    if(counter < 1 && gtk_widget_is_sensitive(GTK_WIDGET(button)))
        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(GTK_WIDGET(button), FALSE);
    /* Update label to show updated counter */
    update_label();
    return;
}


static void
entry_changed_cb(GtkEditable *editable, gpointer data)
{
    (void)data;
    /* Caller has to free the text, so call g_free */
    g_free(prefix);
    /* Get the complete text */
    prefix=gtk_editable_get_chars(editable,0, -1);
    /* Update label to show updated prefix */
    update_label();
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    GtkWidget *button_inc;
    GtkWidget *button_dec;
    GtkWidget *entry_label;
    GtkWidget *entry;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;

    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 5);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    label = gtk_label_new("");
    update_label();

    button_dec = gtk_button_new_with_label("Decrease counter");
    g_signal_connect(button_dec, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(dec_button_click_cb), NULL);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(button_dec, FALSE);

    button_inc = gtk_button_new_with_label("Increase counter");
    g_signal_connect(button_inc, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(inc_button_click_cb), button_dec);

    entry_label = gtk_label_new("Entry prefix to be displayed in the entry below:");

    entry = gtk_entry_new();
    g_signal_connect(entry,"changed", G_CALLBACK(entry_changed_cb), NULL);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), label, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), button_inc, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), button_dec, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), entry_label, 0, 0, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), entry, 0, 0, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    g_free(prefix);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Bzzt!  i said "thanks to all" and then tried to edit and ask another question about the code above.  I modified it to reead in the static char *prefix.  the prefix is the filename.  say 'chat' or 'talk' or 'communicate'.   my additions cause anything typed in the entry space to blow up.  Where to post my additions?

Comment: You can edit you question using the edit button. Otherwise you can add a comment like you have done. Could you clarify a bit, I am not able to understand the problem exactly. Where are you reading from into static char *prefix?

Comment: hm.  if you were able to read my file, slightly modified from your and run thru can -n, then you saw: "Type in filename prefix below:"

Comment: Can you post you code? Here (in question... its not possible in comment) or on site like pastebin.com & post the link?